# How to check the current row with next row and update the current row not using while loop and cursor

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Is there any way other than using the cursor or while loop to check the current row with the next row and update the current row and do this through all rows in the data set?

For example, this is the table we have:

```
id  date                      value
1   2020-09-01 00:00:00.000   0.00
2   2020-09-01 00:15:00.000   0.30
3   2020-09-01 00:30:00.000   0.00
4   2020-09-01 00:45:00.000   0.15
5   2020-09-01 01:00:00.000   0.20
6   2020-09-01 01:15:00.000   0.10
7   2020-09-01 01:30:00.000   0.10
8   2020-09-01 01:45:00.000   0.00
9   2020-09-01 02:00:00.000   0.00



declare @i int = 1, @new_value money = 0.3

while @i <= 10
begin

        select @new_value = iif(value> (@new_value * 0.2) and value < @new_value,
                                       value,
                                       @new_value)
        from table
        where value >= 0.1
        and id = @i + 1;

    set @i = @i + 1
end

select @new_value -- Output will be 0.10
```

This while loop go through each row and update @new_value based on some conditions and then check with the next row.

I would like to see if there is any way not to use a loop or cursor and get the same result.

Comment: what is the role of `we have new value = 3 ` when you said `check the current row with the next row` ? And in the table, you never mention anything about next row

Comment: Updated the question with more details @Squirrel . thanks.

Comment: You can use recursive cte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in recursive cte

```
declare @tbl table
(
    id  int,
    [value] decimal(5,2)
)

insert into @tbl values
(1, 0.00),
(2, 0.30),
(3, 0.00),
(4, 0.15),
(5, 0.20),
(6, 0.10),
(7, 0.10),
(8, 0.00),
(9, 0.00);

declare @new_value decimal(5,2) = 0.3;

with rcte as
(
    select  id, value, 
            new_value = iif(value > (@new_value * 0.2) 
                        and value < @new_value,
                        value,
                        new_value)
    from    @tbl
    where   id  = 1

    union all

    select  t.id, t.value, 
            new_value = iif(t.value > (r.new_value * 0.2) 
                        and t.value < r.new_value,
                        t.value,
                        r.new_value)
    from    rcte r
            inner join @tbl t   on  r.id    = t.id - 1
)
select  *
from    rcte
```

Comment: Thanks! although the performance is still an issue but better than using a loop. my dataset has around 100k rows

Comment: with that kind of computation, you can't avoid some form of loop

Comment: @Squirrel Are you sure this requires a recursive loop per se, looks like window functions should do the trick

Comment: @Charlieface it will be great if it can be with window function

Comment: Just thinking about it: although I get the same results in fiddle, it's not quite the same semantic. If a value is > 0.2 * previous value, but not > 0.2 * (previous value which is > 0.2 of *its* previous), then you and OP exclude it and I include it.

Comment: The Window function is the way to go.  Charlieface's solution is how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the `LAG` window function for this, along with `MIN` aggregation**

```
SELECT MIN(t.value)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        LAG(t.value, 1, 0.3) OVER (ORDER BY t.id) AS prevValue
    FROM [table] AS t
) AS t
WHERE t.value > (t.prevValue * 0.2) AND value < prevValue;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eec9d3/1)

---

I strongly suggest you do not use `money` data type, instead use `decimal`

Comment: thanks! although the output is the same and lag is a better option but the prevValue always keeps changing row by row in my case. In your answer, you get all preValues once and then do the where clause. In my case the where clause should be checked against each row every time and update.